# Source of a problem on pion-proton interaction in elementary particles

Tags: particle-physics, protons, specific-reference, pions

[image]What book is this picture taken from?  It is page 383 of the book in question.

[image]

Comment: Do you physically possess that paper? Or is it a picture of something you found online?

Comment: Why is it necessarily a book? Could be a thesis, an draft of a monograph, lecture notes, any number of things...

Comment: @JonCuster I'm like 70% certain that *Démontrer les inégalites suivantes* means "demonstrate these inequalities" (that's without having taken any French ever in my life). That at least seems to suggest text or longer lecture notes, given the page numbering identified. That said, there's basically nothing to go on here.

Comment: can you give the link you found on line?

Comment: I just think of that. @JonCuster

Comment: I could'n fond it again @annav but i did post the second page wich been sent by a freind

Comment: You mean you don't speak French? @KyleKanos

Comment: @AnastasiaEva Correct, I never learned French. I learned Latin and German in high school, but that was a long time ago.